# How do I copy cookies from Chrome?

Tags: bash, google-chrome, cookies, curl

I am using bash to POST to a website that requires that I be logged in first, so I need to send the request with my login cookie.  I tried logging in and keeping the cookies, but it doesn't work because the site uses javascript to hash the password in a really weird fashion, so instead I'm going to just take my login cookies for the site from Chrome. How do get the cookies from Chrome and format them for Curl?

I'm trying to do this:

```bash
curl --request POST -d "a=X&b=Y" -b "what goes here?" "site.com/a.php"
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

1. Hit F12 to open the developer console (Mac: Cmd+Opt+J)
2. Look at the Network tab.
3. Do whatever you need to on the web site to trigger the action you're interested in
4. Right click the relevant request, and select "Copy as cURL"

This will give you the curl command for the action you triggered, fully populated with cookies and all. You can of course also copy the flags as a basis for new curl commands.

Comment: Doesn't copy cookies in chrome 44

Comment: Can't confirm nor disprove on chrome 44. But it definitely works with chrome 45.

Comment: I have the same issue. Cookies are note being copied and I'm using Chrome 45. I copy them manually by @user2537361 answer below.

Comment: Does not include cookies in Chromium 57.0.2987.98 either.

Comment: If the request is in pending state and you copy it as cURL, it doesn't copy cookies. After request finishes with some status, you can copy it as cURL with cookies. I think it is because server might tell to browser delete cookies and if you copy it before finished, you might have old cookies.

Comment: Chrome 72.0.3626.119 also seems to not copy cookies

Comment: This is not valid anymore.

Comment: I have confirmed this working on this stackoverflow page as of 2019-10-07 on Chrome 77.0.3865.90. I did the steps from the post, where 3. was to upvote this answer. Chrome sent a request to `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21919431/vote/2` (shown as `2` in the list), and the cookie tab shows 9 cookies. I copied as cURL  and pasted it into an editor, and part of the command is `-H 'cookie: prov=...; _ga=...'` containing a total of 9 fields.

Answer (score 18):

In Chrome:

- Open web developer tools (view -> developer -> developer tools)
- Open the Application tab (on older versions, Resources)
- Open the Cookies tree
- Find the cookie you are interested in.

In the terminal

- add `--cookie "cookiename=cookievalue"` to your curl request.

Comment: You can specify multiple via 'name1=value1; name2=value2'.

Comment: I needed to triple click the cookie to get to select

Comment: No need. Right Click on a request under Network > Header Options > Cookies. And copy the curl again.

Answer (score 13):

Can't believe no one has mentioned this. Here's the easiest and quickest way.

Simply open up your browser's `Developer Tools`, click on the `Console` tab, and lastly within the console, simply type the following & press ENTER...

```
console.log(document.cookie)
```

The results will be immediately printed in proper syntax. Simply highlight it and copy it.

Comment: I wouldn't call it proper format. It prints a semicolon-separated list, whereas the proper syntax has a bunch of `TRUE` / `FALSE` thingies.

Comment: Nice solution but unfortunately it won't work for HttpOnly cookies.

Answer (score 11):

**There's an even easier way to do this in Chrome/Chromium.**
The open source Chrome extension
[cookies.txt](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/get-cookiestxt/bgaddhkoddajcdgocldbbfleckgcbcid/related?hl=en) exports cookie data in a cookies.txt file, and generates an optional ready-made wget command.

*I have nothing to do with the extension, it just works really well.

Comment: The link is broken. The extension does not seem to exist anymore.

Comment: Indeed, fixed the link

Comment: This link is broken again? I have this extension installed locally and it is great, I can't find it anymore in the webstore to link other users to though

Comment: Here's a search link that's perhaps less likely to break: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/cookies.txt . Currently for me, the top result is "Get cookies.txt", Offered by: Rahul Shaw

Comment: Please be cautios! It seems that this extension is stealing your cookies https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/31465

Comment: The link to cookies.txt is dead due to the extension being malicious

Answer (score 4):

I was curious if others were reporting that chrome doesn't allow "copy as curl" feature to have cookies anymore.

It then occurred to me that this is like a security idea.  If you visit `example.com`, copying requests as curl to `example.com` will have cookies.  However, copying requests to other domains or subdomains will sanitize the cookies.  `a.example.com` or `test.com` will not have cookies for example.

Comment: I can confirm this is the case, at least in Chrome 66.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that wants all of the cookies for a site, but doesn't want to use an extension:

- Open developer tools -> Application -> Cookies.
- Select the first cookie in the list and hit `Ctrl`/`Cmd`-`A`
- Copy all of the data in this table with `Ctrl`/`Cmd`-`C`

Now you have a TSV (tab-separated value) string of cookie data. You can process this in any language you want, but in Python (for example):

```
import io
import pandas as pd

cookie_str = """[paste cookie str here]"""

# Copied from the developer tools window.
cols = ['name', 'value', 'domain', 'path', 'max_age', 'size', 'http_only', 'secure', 'same_party', 'priority']

# Parse into a dataframe.
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(cookie_str), sep='\t', names=cols, index_col=False)
```

Now you can export them in [Netscape format](http://www.cookiecentral.com/faq/#3.5):

```
# Fill in NaNs and format True/False for cookies.txt.
df = df.fillna(False).assign(flag=True).replace({True: 'TRUE', False: 'FALSE'})
# Get unix timestamp from max_age
max_age = (
    df.max_age
    .replace({'Session': np.nan})
    .pipe(pd.to_datetime))
start = pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01", tz='UTC')
max_age = (
    ((max_age - start) // pd.Timedelta('1s'))
    .fillna(0)  # Session expiry are 0s
    .astype(int))  # Floats end with ".0"
df = df.assign(max_age=max_age)

cookie_file_cols = ['domain', 'flag', 'path', 'secure', 'max_age', 'name', 'value']
with open('cookies.txt') as fh:
  # Python's cookiejar wants this header.
  fh.write('# Netscape HTTP Cookie File\n')
  df[cookie_file_cols].to_csv(fh, sep='\t', index=False, header=False)
```

And finally, back to the shell:

```
# Get user agent from navigator.userAgent in devtools
wget -U $USER_AGENT --load-cookies cookies.txt $YOUR_URL
```

Comment: For the record, under Ubuntu, ctrl-A, ctrl-C didn't work - I had to manually select the cookies by dragging the selection. Also Developer tools -> Application -> cookies isn't so obvious if you're not used to Developer tools: "Application" is under a tab that you only see by clicking a » to the right of other tabs.