# save login session in curl for use another php file

Tags: curl

i want to login a web site with curl php an i can it
but no active login and when i call another php file for request this site I see that no avtive login 
I want save login information for use it in the other php file but iam not slove it.

a.php:

this code is ok and i can login site but when call b.php login session is lose

=====================

b.php:

I want to do  when call a.php and login to site when call b.php it is work ok and not lose login seesion ( a.php )

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760213/save-cookies-between-two-curl-requests

Comment: curl CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE parameters

Answer (score 0):

a.php should at least contain:

```
$cookies = tempnam('/tmp','cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);
```

b.php should at least contain:

```
$cookies = tempnam('/tmp','cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
```

CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR is the path where curl will write the cookies from the http response.

CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE is the path where curl will read the cookies for the http request.