# Log into a site and download a file with cURL

Tags: bash, shell, curl, post

I am trying to log into a website via curl. The site is this:

```
https://web.spaggiari.eu/home/app/default/login.php
```

To later download a file from this site using this command::

```
curl -Lv https://web.spaggiari.eu/fml/app/default/xml_export.php?stampa=%3Astampa%3A&report_name=&tipo=agenda&data=03+11+20&autore_id=6583250&tipo_export=EVENTI_AGENDA_STUDENTI&quad=%3Aquad%3A&materia_id=&classe_id=%3Aclasse_id%3A&gruppo_id=%3Agruppo_id%3A&ope=RPT&dal=2020-11-03&al=2020-11-03&formato=xls
```

Without logging in, however, the source code of the page is downloaded, and not the xls file that I would like to download. In fact, using this command you can see that authentication is required:

```
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x5605f44e3f50)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x5605f44e3f50)
*   Trying 159.69.199.242...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 149997 ms for 3 (transfer 0x5605f44e3f50)
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x5605f44e3f50)
* Connected to web.spaggiari.eu (159.69.199.242) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.spaggiari.eu
*  start date: May 29 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: May 29 12:00:00 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "web.spaggiari.eu" matched certs "*.spaggiari.eu"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=GeoTrust RSA CA 2018
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /fml/app/default/xml_export.php?stampa=%3Astampa%3A HTTP/1.1
> Host: web.spaggiari.eu
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: nginx/1.18.0
< Date: Wed, 04 Nov 2020 10:07:44 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN;
< Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' filesystem: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' *.spaggiari.eu https://ajax.googleapis.com/ https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ https://code.jquery.com/ https://d31qbv1cthcecs.cloudfront.net/atrk.js https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.googletagmanager.com/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/;frame-ancestors 'self' file: *.spaggiari.eu;
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=u2nkberujpq5t8ja8sh7u21jl2htt5vn; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Location: ../../../home/app/default/login.php
< X-ZVersion: c
< Pragma: public
< Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
< 
* Connection #0 to host web.spaggiari.eu left intact
```

Through the DevTools of my browser I understood that the authentication request is actually performed to web.spaggiari.eu/auth-p7/app/default/AuthApi4.php?a=aLoginPw‌ using a form POST.
I initially tried using the usual curl commands to log into a site:

```
curl --anyauth --user mail:password web.spaggiari.eu/auth-p7/app/default/AuthApi4.php?a=aLoginPwd

curl --user mail:password https://web.spaggiari.eu/auth-p7/app/default/AuthApi4.php?a=aLoginPwd

curl --data mail:password https://web.spaggiari.eu/auth-p7/app/default/AuthApi4.php?a=aLoginPwd
```

Using these commands, however, I could not solve the problem and the output was always the same.
So I searched for many solutions on the internet and I realized that I could copy as cURL what I find inside the DevTools of my browser when I try to login (I use "Edge Version 88.0.680.1 (Official Build) dev (64 bit)").

This is the curl command I found when I attempted to log into the site:

```
curl 'https://web.spaggiari.eu/auth-p7/app/default/AuthApi4.php?a=aLoginPwd'\
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4295.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/88.0.680.1' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'Origin: https://web.spaggiari.eu' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Referer: https://web.spaggiari.eu/home/app/default/login.php?target=atv&mode=' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: it,it-IT;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6' \
  -H 'Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1118066416.1604149840; webrole=gen; webidentity=S6583250C; __auc=b7176b856757ec8351961876044; weblogin=mail.example@example.it; PHPSESSID=cjgqkc6oih4k77ufg2v20enhgkl168em; __asc=4f7867e8175923893ed8b4d9596' \
  --data-raw 'cid=&uid=mail.example%40example.it&pwd=password&pin=&target=' \
  --compressed
```

This is the curl command I found when I logged in successfully:

```
curl 'https://web.spaggiari.eu/home/app/default/login_ok_redirect.php' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' \
  -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
  -H 'Origin: https://web.spaggiari.eu' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4295.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/88.0.680.1' \
  -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
  -H 'Referer: https://web.spaggiari.eu/home/app/default/login.php?target=atv&mode=' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: it,it-IT;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6' \
  -H 'Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1118066416.1604149840; webrole=gen; webidentity=S6583250C; __auc=b7176b841757ec8351585876044; _gid=GA1.2.115190717.1604390974; weblogin=mail.example@example.it; __asc=8123be1b178230d092a7920630f; LAST_REQUESTED_TARGET=atv; PHPSESSID=ghcl8g9otsje4psuq6vflk4kqhbsho9q' \
  --data-raw 'custcode=&login=mail.example%40example.it&password=password&pin=' \
  --compressed
```

This is the curl command I found when I downloaded the xls file I want to download:

```
curl 'https://web.spaggiari.eu/fml/app/default/xml_export.php?stampa=%3Astampa%3A&report_name=&tipo=agenda&data=03+11+20&autore_id=6583250&tipo_export=EVENTI_AGENDA_STUDENTI&quad=%3Aquad%3A&materia_id=&classe_id=%3Aclasse_id%3A&gruppo_id=%3Agruppo_id%3A&ope=RPT&dal=2020-11-03&al=2020-11-03&formato=xls' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4295.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/88.0.680.1' \
  -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: it,it-IT;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6' \
  -H 'Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1118066416.1604149840; webrole=gen; webidentity=S6583250C; __auc=b4701b841757ec8351585876044; weblogin=mail.example@example.it; PHPSESSID=cjgqkc6oih4k77ufg2v20edmmkl168em; __asc=4f6735e8175928173ed8b4d6783' \
  --compressed
```

Although I tried to use these commands I was unable to login and download the xls file.
Ask me for any other details that might be helpful in solving the problem.
Do you have any solutions that I could try? Thanks everyone for the help.

EDIT:

This is the output of the first command obtained from the DevTools. The last string maybe means that I am logged into the site.

```
* Expire in 11 ms for 1 (transfer 0x56303982af50)
* Expire in 14 ms for 1 (transfer 0x56303982af50)
*   Trying 159.69.199.244...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 149978 ms for 3 (transfer 0x56303982af50)
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x56303982af50)
* Connected to web.spaggiari.eu (159.69.199.244) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.spaggiari.eu
*  start date: May 29 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: May 29 12:00:00 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "web.spaggiari.eu" matched certs "*.spaggiari.eu"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=GeoTrust RSA CA 2018
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /auth-p7/app/default/AuthApi4.php?a=aLoginPwd HTTP/1.1
> Host: web.spaggiari.eu
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> Connection: keep-alive
> Accept: */*
> X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4295.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/88.0.680.1
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
> Origin: https://web.spaggiari.eu
> Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
> Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
> Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
> Referer: https://web.spaggiari.eu/home/app/default/login.php?target=atv&mode=
> Accept-Language: it,it-IT;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
> Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1118066416.1604149840; webrole=gen; webidentity=S6583250C; __auc=b7176b841757ec8351585876044; weblogin=t.dordoni@ccgraphos.it; PHPSESSID=cjgqkc6oih4k77ufg2v20edmmkl168em; __asc=4f2356e8175928173ed8b4d9596
> Content-Length: 63
> 
* upload completely sent off: 63 out of 63 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.18.0
< Date: Wed, 04 Nov 2020 11:00:29 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN;
< Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' filesystem: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' *.spaggiari.eu https://ajax.googleapis.com/ https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ https://code.jquery.com/ https://d31qbv1cthcecs.cloudfront.net/atrk.js https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.googletagmanager.com/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/;frame-ancestors 'self' file: *.spaggiari.eu;
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=46e4ipq6v6dh32mv1mvdvf4sb4ukpb84; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
< X-ZVersion: c
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Pragma: public
< Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
< 
* Connection #0 to host web.spaggiari.eu left intact
{"time":"2020-11-04T12:00:28+01:00","data":{"auth":{"verified":true,"loggedIn":true,"actionRequested":false,"hints":[],"errors":[],"accountInfo":{"type":"S","id":6583250,"cognome":"NAME","nome":"SURNAME","cid":"MIIT0065"},"redirects":[],"aMode":"sam","mMode":"SEML","errCod":[]},"pfolio":false},"error":[],"api":{"env":"production","AuthSpa":{"version":"2.8.4"}
```

But when I try to run the last command to download the xls file I wrote, the output is this and I can't download the file.

```
* Expire in 7 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55ca86595f50)
* Expire in 9 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55ca86595f50)
*   Trying 212.83.134.163...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 149986 ms for 3 (transfer 0x55ca86595f50)
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55ca86595f50)
* Connected to web.spaggiari.eu (212.83.134.163) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.spaggiari.eu
*  start date: May 29 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: May 29 12:00:00 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "web.spaggiari.eu" matched certs "*.spaggiari.eu"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=GeoTrust RSA CA 2018
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /fml/app/default/xml_export.php?stampa=%3Astampa%3A&report_name=&tipo=agenda&data=03+11+20&autore_id=6583250&tipo_export=EVENTI_AGENDA_STUDENTI&quad=%3Aquad%3A&materia_id=&classe_id=%3Aclasse_id%3A&gruppo_id=%3Agruppo_id%3A&ope=RPT&dal=2020-11-03&al=2020-11-03&formato=xls HTTP/1.1
> Host: web.spaggiari.eu
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> Connection: keep-alive
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4295.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/88.0.680.1
> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
> Sec-Fetch-Site: none
> Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
> Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
> Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
> Accept-Language: it,it-IT;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
> Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1118066416.1604149840; webrole=gen; webidentity=S6583250C; __auc=b7176b841757ec8351585876044; weblogin=t.dordoni@ccgraphos.it; PHPSESSID=cjgqkc6oih4k77ufg2v20edmmkl168em; __asc=4f2356e8175928173ed8b4d9596
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: nginx/1.18.0
< Date: Wed, 04 Nov 2020 11:10:03 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN;
< Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' filesystem: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' *.spaggiari.eu https://ajax.googleapis.com/ https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ https://code.jquery.com/ https://d31qbv1cthcecs.cloudfront.net/atrk.js https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.googletagmanager.com/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/;frame-ancestors 'self' file: *.spaggiari.eu;
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Location: ../../../home/app/default/login.php
< X-ZVersion: c
< Pragma: public
< Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
< 
* Connection #0 to host web.spaggiari.eu left intact
```

Comment: Check out curl's `-c`/`--cookie-jar` option, it should let you store the cookie that is sent in answer to the auth request and use it in subsequent requests. That said your last option should have worked, so it could be useful if you posted what exactly happened (errors, specific HTTP response codes, etc.) when you tried it

Comment: @Aaron I am adding the command output in the post.

Comment: @Aaron I added some information in the post. They are useful?

Comment: When you do your auth request, the answers contains a `< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=...` which is the relevant cookie. That cookie however doesn't appear in your requests obtained from the dev tool, which is why the responses are for an unauthenticated user.

Comment: You should check whether your original curl authentication request returned that cookie, I don't think you'll need all the other parameters the dev tool returned. Whichever request you end up using you'll want to set a cookie jar for it which will store the cookie sent in the response, and reference that cookie jar again in the requests that need to be authenticated. I don't remember the exact syntax but I've found a duplicate that goes into those details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save cookies between two curl requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760213/save-cookies-between-two-curl-requests)

Comment: @Aaron This is what I get using "curl --cookie-jar cookie.txt 'https://www.example.com' (with the command to LOG IN): # HttpOnly_web.spaggiari.eu FALSE / TRUE 0 PHPSESSID 845602gnor5kg7jcnlmcgsfvce8iklol

Comment: You've got a PHPSESSID so it looks good. Just reuse the cookie jar in the XLS download request.

Comment: This solved my problem. thanks a lot