# what I'm missing here with curl/bash?

Tags: bash, curl, download, cloud-hosting

Yo there, I'm trying to use curl to download/upload files to rapidgator.net.
But download is the most important task; in the past I've done this easily, but
now it is downloading only the front page.

The idea is to load a file with the urls required and then pass it to curl as argument, first I make a cookie file

```
curl -X POST \
--cookie-jar cookie\
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-d '{"username":"somebox@somegmail.com","password":"thepassword"}' \
https://rapidgator.net/api/v2/user/login? > /dev/null
```

By the api, this should have been right, but it only generates a valid cookie with

```
https://rapidgator.net/api/v2/user/?login=somemail@someplace.com&password=thepassword
 > /dev/null
```

The reply is conform in the expected way (as documented [here](https://rapidgator.net/article/api/user#login) ), but it isn't saving to the stated cookie file.

And once the cookie is generated, the filelist is created and the download is made in the next way

```
for i in $(cat filelist) \ 
      do 
          curl -x -L -O -C - --cookie cookie_file -s "$url/$i" \
done
```

But it only download the regular front page, so it seems the cookie isn't working.
And since there are long lists, doing one by one isn't viable.

So how can generate the cookie and download with curl?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
Thanks for the support.
The detail is the api itself, since

```
username
```

is implemented as

```
login
```

once this is updated to generate the cookie the curl download is only adjusted to

```
  curl -L -O -C - --cookie cookie_file $i \
```

Thanks for the support!

Comment: How do you create `filelist`?

Comment: APIs don't usually use cookies. The Login API returns an access token that you're supposed to use in future requests. Cookies are normally only used by web pages.

Comment: Is that another copying error? You have a different filename in `--cookie-jar` than `--cookie`.

Comment: I dump it from the clipboard one line at the time, and make the for loop to avoid the format limitations of -K argument, the token is saved in the cookie, but I don't know how to pass it alone to  curl.

Comment: You can pass it as a URL parameter, e.g.: `/api/v2/user/info?token=arsd4h37ecfkdqd16uolf5nai1`

Comment: Or `/api/v2/file/download?file_id=n6eg62ga6hr5r6hjpepfh7asf2&token=n6eg62ga6hr5r6hjpepfh7asf2` to download a file.

Comment: This question is very close to the this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760213/save-cookies-between-two-curl-requests Not a duplicate but close relative. The answers might provide a solution direction.