# How can I download cookies from multiple domains in a single file in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

In Firefox, I can download cookies from all domains using [Ganbo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ganbo/).

```
# Cookies for this tab
# Click here to download them
# Click here to download cookies for all domains
```

However, I could not find a single extension in chrome that download cookies from all domains in a single file. With Chrome I can only download cookies for a single domain by using [Get cookies.txt](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/get-cookiestxt/bgaddhkoddajcdgocldbbfleckgcbcid) or extensions like that.

I checked [How do I copy cookies from Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21919156). But the solutions there does not solve my particular problem.

How can I download cookies from multiple domains in a single file in chrome?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? (This smells like an X/Y Problem)

Comment: "How can I download cookies for all domains in Chrome?"  - as far as I know **you can't** - at least, not without dumping your local Chrome profile database.

Comment: You aren't "downloading" cookies, btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Locate your `Cookies` file in your Chrome profile directory:

   - On Windows, this is typically `C:\Users\<your_username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies`

     - via [Where does Chrome store cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021764/where-does-chrome-store-cookies)
   - There is no file extension.
2. [Use a SQLite database file editor](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/) to open the `Cookies` file.

   - You may need to copy the `Cookies` file elsewhere first if Chrome has a lock on the file (Windows File Explorer can safely copy locked-files as it uses the Shadow Copy API for locked files).
3. Dump the `cookies` table.

---

With screenshots:

### Step 1: Locate the `Cookies` file:

[image]

### Step 2: Open the `Cookies` file in a SQLite editor:

[image]

### Step 3: Access the `cookies` table:

Cookie **values** are not stored in the `value` column - they're actually stored in the `encrypted_value` and encrypted with DPAPI (on Windows). I don't know how they're encrypted or stored on macOS, Linux, Android, or any other OS (as DPAPI is specific to Windows).

This QA has an example of how to decrypt the cookie values on Windows using C#: [Encrypted cookies in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532870/encrypted-cookies-in-chrome)

[image]

Comment: It is my fault that I did not give some details earlier. I am using Linux Mint (Ubuntu). I actually want to use the cookie file with `youtube-dl`. It needs to be in Firefox format. `Get cookies.txt` give it in firefox format but not for all domains. Do you have any idea how to get cookies for all domains in firefox format, in Linux Mint (Ubuntu). It will be great if you could extend the answer for the given details.